Symmetry of an operator
Let $\pmb{\sigma}=(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)$ where $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\sigma_1= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_2= 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
i & 0
\end{pmatrix},\,
\sigma_3= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let $f,g\in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})$. What i am trying to show is that
\begin{equation}
\left((\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)f,(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)g\right)_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})}=\left(f,(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)^2g\right)_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})}
\end{equation}
I have really no idea on how to prove it, so any suggestion will be really helpful. Thank you all in advance.
Edit As pointed out in the comments, the equality is off a minus sign, so what is true is that
$$
\left((\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)f,(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)g\right)_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})}
=
-\left(f,(\pmb{\sigma}\cdot\nabla)^2g\right)_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})}
=-\left(f,\Delta g\right)_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^{3},\mathbb{C}^{2})}\,.
$$

This seems to me like it’s off by a minus sign, but otherwise it’s just the standard proof, using integration by parts, that the derivative operator is anti-Hermitian (while also using the fact that Pauli matrices are all Hermitian).

I too think there is a problem with a minus sign, because of the integration by parts process. For context, this property is taken by the proof of Lemma 5, at pag. 8 of this article.

Maybe I’m wrong, but it feels to me like a typo on the author’s part. The proof will still go through if you just add a minus sign throughout.
